# How to find the physical/absolute path to the virtual directory by using a port number

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, networking, iis

I would like to know what all are the ways by which we can get the physical or absolute path of a webserver (In windows). Is there is any way to find the path Just by the port number.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need to since the port dictates which website is running.  If you had 2 seperate websites for example on different ports and pointed them at different virtual directories, the physical path would already be different depending on which one you were on.  You could get each absolute path using each virtual root path.